# error: expected primary-expression before "__attribute__";

Tags: c, solaris

I am compiling a C program on Solaris 10 for x86, this is a part linked:

```
>yyerrlab1:/*Suppress GCC warning that yyerrlab1 is unused when no action*/
>#if defined (__GNUC_MINOR__)&&2093<=(__GNUC__*1000+__GNUC_MINOR__) 
> __attribute__((__unused__))
>#endif
>goto yyerrlab2;
```

The code is written in a file named yacc.y.
When I compile the program by makefile, the result comes out to be:

```
>bison -d -p syn yacc.y
>yacc.y:conflicts:7shifts/reduce
>mv yacc.tab.h yacc.h
>mv yacc.tab.c yacc.c
>yacc.tab.c: in function 'int synparse()';
>yacc.tab.c:1543:error:expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"
>yacc.tab.c:1543:error:expected ";" before "__attribute__"
```

What's wrong with the code?And how can I fix it?

Comment: I am really concerned with the goto line

Answer (score 4):

The code is using a GCC-specific language extension called [attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) to indicate that the label might be unused.  Ordinarily, GCC emits a warning for an unused label, since it can be indicative of a bug, but in this case since the code is autogenerated by YACC, it's not sure if it's used or not.  So, this attribute suppresses the warning in case it's not used.

It appears that the compiler you're using doesn't support the `__attribute__` syntax.  The `#if` test is supposed to protect against that, but apparently the test failed, either because you're using some odd variant of GCC that doesn't support it, or you're using a different compiler that's pretending to be GCC.

To fix it, either switch to a modern GCC version if possible, or modify the `#if` test to be false with your compiler.  The quick and dirty fix would be to just remove the `#if` completely, since the `__attribute__` tag isn't necessary for correctness, it's just there to remove a potential compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick&dirty work around remove the following lines from `yacc.y`:

```
#if defined (__GNUC_MINOR__)&&2093<=(__GNUC__*1000+__GNUC_MINOR__) 
 __attribute__((__unused__))
#endif
```

When compiling your sources with this modification it would lead to a warning regaring the unused label `yyerrlab1`, which you could silently ignore.

This solution will not influence the intented functionality of the code.

Comment: I can not ignore the warning, it can not generate a yacc.o file because of the errors.

Comment: I meant to ignore the warning which would be issued if you would have applied the quick&dirty fix I proposed in my answer. I did not meant you should ignore the error described in your question. @Betsy